# Convert Specific String to JSON Object

Tags: node.js, json, string, typeconverter

```
const test ="[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=samle}]";
```

I need to convert this string to a JSON object. It will dynamically load like this string. I need to particular string to convert to a JSON object.

JSON.parse(test) command not working for this. I attached the error here.

[image]

Comment: Try JSON.parse(...)

Comment: It is not working for this string bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific string, you'd have to parse it yourself.

```
const test = '[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=samle}]';
const obj = {};
test.split(/[{}]/)[1].split(/, /).forEach((elm) => {
  const entry = elm.split('=');
  obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
});
```

What I am doing is splitting the string on the braces and selecting the second element (utilising regex) then splitting that on comma and space (again regex) then loop over the result and assign to an object.
You can then JSON.stringify(obj) for the result.

:edit:

For the second string you've asked for there is another, potentially more refined, answer. You'll need to first replace the = with : (I've again used a regex), then you use a regex to match the words and sentence and use a function to add the quotes.

```
const test = '[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=samle}]';
const test2 = "[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=rrr additional Detail, medicationType={medicationTypeId=3333, medicationType=Tablet}, endDate=2022-12-30}]";

const replaced = test.replace(/=/g,':')
const replaced2 = test2.replace(/=/g, ':');

const replacer = function(match){
    return '"' + match + '"';
}

const replacedQuote = replaced.replace(/(?!\s)[-?\w ?]+/g,replacer);
const replaced2Quote = replaced2.replace(/(?!\s)[-?\w ?]+/g,replacer);


const obj = JSON.parse(replacedQuote);
const obj2 = JSON.parse(replaced2Quote);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, It is working....... Thank You sooo much bro. The String is dynamically changed in this pattern. I cannot find a way to do this. Again Thank You very much Bro

Comment: "[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=rrr additional Detail, medicationType={medicationTypeId=3333, medicationType=Tablet}, endDate=2022-12-30}]"

Comment: If have another map inside the String like this. How to do bro?

Comment: Instead of my parsing you might be able to do a replace = with : and just JSON.parse()

Comment: Sorry Not understand bro

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that Json means javascript object notation, so you need to create a JavaScript object to get started:

```
const test ="[{contactId=2525, additionDetail=samle}]";
let obj = Object.create(null)
```

You can now define your variable as one of the object properties :

```
obj.test = test
```

Now we have a JavaScript object and we can convert it to json:

```
let convertedToJson = JSON.stringify(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [{contactId=2525, additionDetail=samle}]

this is not a valid JSON-string, and it cannot be parsed by JSON.parse()

the correct JSON-string would be:

```
const test ='[{"contactId":2525, "additionDetail":"samle"}]';
```

Comment: yeah It is correct. But I needed the above dynamically change string convert to JSON. (without changing dynamically load String)